# Make navigation menu span length of browser

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation

I am trying to get my navigation menu to span the entire length of my blog. Right now it is off center to the right and a bit too short. How do I make it longer?

Also, you'll notice that my navigation menu is not at the very top of the page, which is where I would like it to be. How do I fix that as well?

And that's not it! My navigation menu is sticky, but when you scroll past it.. it gets thrown to the left side of the page. What to do?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Below is some of the code. And here is the site: http://www.studywithstyleblog.com

```
<div id="navigationbar">
#cssnav { 
border: 0px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: auto;
font: $(tabs.font); /* Template Designer - Change Font Type, Size, Etc */
color: $(tabs.text.color); /* Template Designer - Change Font Size */
}
#cssnav ul {
#cssnav ul {
background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;
_background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Menu Background */
height: 40px; /* Change Height of Menu */
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#cssnav li {
float: none; /* none = centre */
display: inline-block;
padding: 0px;
}
#cssnav li a {
background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;
_background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Menu Background */
display: block;
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
font: $(tabs.font); /* Template Designer - Change Font Type, Size, Etc */
text-decoration: none;
}
#cssnav > ul > li > a {
color: $(tabs.text.color); /* Template Designer - Change Font Color */
}
#cssnav ul ul a { 
color: $(tabs.text.color); /* Template Designer - Change Color */
}
#cssnav li > a:hover, #cssnav ul li:hover {
color: $(tabs.selected.text.color); /* Template Designer - Change Font Color on Hover */
background-color: $(tabs.selected.background.color); /* Template Designer - Change Font Background on Hover */
text-decoration: none;
}
#cssnav li ul {
background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;
_background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Menu Background */
display: none;
height: auto;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border: -5px;
position: absolute;
width: 300px; /* Change Width Of DropDown Menu */
z-index:9999;
}
#cssnav li:hover ul {
}
#cssnav li li {
background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;
_background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Background */
display: block;
float: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 300px; /* Change Width Of DropDown Menu */
}
#cssnav li:hover li a {
background: #FFFFFF; /* Template Designer - Change Background of Link on Hover */
}
#cssnav li ul a {
display: block;
height: auto;
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
text-align: left;
}
#cssnav li ul a:hover, #cssnav li ul li:hover > a {
color: $(tabs.selected.text.color); /* Template Designer - Change Text Color on Hover */
background-color: $(tabs.selected.background.color); /* Template Designer - Change Background on Hover */
border: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
}
/*-------- Begin Drop Down Menu -------*/
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the nav bar being offset change the css rule #menubar and get rid of the width rule.

```
#menubar {
  background: #000000;
  /* width: 1120px; */
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 45px;
}
```

To make the nav bar always be at the top of the page add the following style atributes to the sticknav element.

```
<sticknav style="position: fixed;top: 0px;">
```

Comment: I actually just changed that to be 100% and it ended up making the nav menu span the entire length on the scroll, just not before. What should I do to make it the entire length prior to the scroll? Visit the page to see what I mean.. @Ellery

Comment: add a style tag to the stickynav element so it forces its position to always be fixed

<sticknav class="fixed" style="top: 0px; position:fixed;">

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much @Ellery :)